# reading json / adding to it

Tags: c++, json

Im new at anything json.

I am trying to use this lib made by nlohmann
https://github.com/nlohmann/json

I need to be able to read if my component is added to the json, if not then add it to the list.

Then i need to check if a parameter exists by checking its name, if it does not exist push_back to the list.

I have added comments where i need the help.

Thanks.

```
                json jresult;
                jresult["userParameters"] = {  };

                // check if component exists in userParameters, else add it
                if ( == component_names[i])
                {
                    // check if parameter name exists if not add the parameters
                    if (!= userParam->name()) {
                        
                        // then push it onto the list
                        .push_back(
                            {
                                {"name", userParam->name()},
                                {"expression", userParam->expression()},
                                {"comment", userParam->comment()},
                            });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    jresult["userParameters"].push_back(
                        {
                            { "component", component_names[i] },
                            { "parameters", {
                                {"name", userParam->name()},
                                {"expression", userParam->expression()},
                                {"comment", userParam->comment()},
                            }}
                        });
                }
```

Comment: Consider using [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch jsoncpp does not have many examples. would you know how to do this with it?

Comment: `if (jresult["userParameters"]["component"] == component_names[i])`, does it work?

Comment: @kiner_shah that will create a "component" key if it doesn't exist, so don't do that.

Comment: @cmannett85, from what I understood, OP needs to compare if there is a "component" with value `component_names[i]`, but yeah I think it first needs to be checked if a "component" exists and if not, then create a "component" and assign `component_names[i]` to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto jresult = json{{"userParameters", json::array()}};

// check if component exists in userParameters, else add it
auto& user_params = jresult["userParameters"];
auto it = std::find_if(user_params.begin(), user_params.end(), [&](auto&& param) {
    return param["component"] == component_names[i];
});

if (it != user_params.end())
{
    // check if parameter name exists if not add the parameters
    auto& params = (*it)["parameters"];
    it = std::find_if(params.begin(), params.end(), [&](auto&& param) {
        return param["name"] == userParam->name();
    });
    if (it == params.end()) {
        
        // then push it onto the list
        params.push_back(
            {
                {"name", userParam->name()},
                {"expression", userParam->expression()},
                {"comment", userParam->comment()},
            });
    }
}
else {
    user_params.push_back(
        {
            { "component", component_names[i] },
            { "parameters", json::array({{
                {"name", userParam->name()},
                {"expression", userParam->expression()},
                {"comment", userParam->comment()},
            }})}
        });
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ETYqcoP9f